# Velodyne rawdata.cc does not appear to read hardware time stamp

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [HDL-32E User's Manual & Programming Guide](http://velodynelidar.com/lidar/products/manual/63-9113%20HDL-32E%20manual_Rev%20E_NOV2012.pdf), pg 9:

***Packet Format and Status Byte for GPS Time Stamping**

The 6 extra bytes at the end of the HDL-32E data packet are used to report GPS timing. For every packet, the last 6 bytes are formatted as follows:

     4 bytes: 32 bit unsigned integer time stamp. This value represents microseconds from the top of the hour to the first laser firing in the packet.

     2 bytes: blank*

Unless I am failing to follow the code, [rawdata.cc](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/lib/rawdata.cc) never touches the time stamp bytes in the data packet.

**Question:** Are we to assume that the time stamp reported by `pcl_ros/bag_to_pcd` is the time the UDP packet was received in software as opposed to the hardware-provided time stamp?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200853/velodyne-rawdata.cc-does-not-appear-to-read-hardware-time-stamp/) by [brianthelion](https://answers.ros.org/users/21360/brianthelion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you are correct. The Velodyne driver was originally written for the -64 model which has a very similar protocol, but no GPS. I did the first validation of the -32 for Jack, because he only had a -64 on hand, and no changes were required to the base code. Since that wasn't really requested by anyone at the time (Clearpath being the only -32 user), the extra code to handle the GPS wasn't added.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianthelion](https://answers.ros.org/users/21360/brianthelion/) on 2015-01-13**:
What's the best way to retrieve the hardware time stamp given that the driver isn't parsing it? Patch the driver? Something else?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-01-19**:
Yes, I think you'd need to patch the driver. If you can make a patch that works with all the supported models, please submit a merge request so we can add it to the standard driver.

**Comment by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on 2017-10-20**:
I was just wondering if this change been merged into the latest velodyne driver because the comments on rawdata.cc file says HDL-64E? If it has been updated, does it work for the VLP16 as well?